# delete functionality does not work - Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-events

I am building one site in YII.
I have made one functionality like delete for one of my controller.
I have defined my access rules like this.

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('index', 'create', 'delete', 'update'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('deny',
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
    );

}
```

still If I try to access delete functionality even after login, It gives me this error.

```
CHttpException

You are not authorized to perform this action. (C:\xampp\htdocs\framework\web\auth\CAccessControlFilter.php:170)
```

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('index', 'create', 'delete', 'update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('deny',
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );

    }
Simple Thing you are allowing for all user and also deny for all user then how it will be work now login with demo/demo or admin/admin you can delete
```